# Pandas DataFrame to Hive Query for Insert

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, hive, hiveql

My question is whether there is a way to generate a HiveQL with `insert` statement with X of columns and Y of rows into something like from Pandas' DataFrame object:

```
query = "INSERT INTO %s SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s from " % (
    table_name, column_names[0], column_names[1], column_names[2], column_names[3], column_names[4], column_names[5], column_names[6])
```

I have the following dataframe as an example:

```
  metric predict_date         value        y_date      x_date  ... (many columns) 
0  sales   2017-10-01  7.539010e+06   2016-06-01   2017-09-01
1  sales   2017-11-01  8.364379e+06   2016-07-01   2017-09-01
2  sales   2017-12-01  9.533355e+06   2016-08-01   2017-09-01
.
.
.
(many rows)
```

The use case here is just getting that query constructed.

*NOTE:*

- Pandas' [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) is actually writing to the SQL which I do not want for my use case.
- I believe Spark is an option, but is there a quick-and-easy way to generate this as setting up Spark cluster takes time. :-)

Comment: That query is badly formed; don't use string formatting to create queries. It's also invalid. Are you asking how to use pandas to query a Hive DB? I'm a bit lost on what your expected output should be.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the reply. What's your suggested way to build the query?  The end result is a query in string type for my use case.

I am not asking how to use pandas to query a Hive DB, I am asking the opposite where to use pandas dataframe to insert data into HiveDB table.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean query. I'm not sure if theres a connector for Hive as part of pandas, I used pyodbc library in my work. But no statement for SQL should be made using string formatting, it should be parameterized to prevent sql injection and to increase efficiency.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks. The query is not actually for real operation, but more like a visual preview for the user.

ODBC is for actually making the insert operation which is not my use case.